# How to pass "$email" to WooCommerce emails template files if not available by default

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, parameters, email-notifications

I've checked many threads on the platform. But there is no thread which explains how to use the conditional `$email>id` parameter straight into a template.

This is what I have in `email-header.php`:

```
<div style="width:600px;" id="template_header_image">
    <?php
    if ( $img = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_header_image' ) ) {
        echo '<p style="margin-top:0;"><img width="80%" height="auto" src="' . esc_url( $img ) . '" alt="' . get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) . '" /></p>';
    }
    if( $email->id == 'customer_processing_order'  ) {
        echo '<img alt="order in processing" src="https/example.com/image.png" />';
}
?>                          
</div>
```

The src is an example. The `if( $email->id == 'customer_processing_order' )` is not working.

It seems that parameter `$email` is not being picked up. I tried to call it with `global $email`; but this also does not work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In /includes/class-wc-emails.php we see that only `$email_heading` is passed via `wc_get_template()`

```php
/**
 * Get the email header.
 *
 * @param mixed $email_heading Heading for the email.
 */
public function email_header( $email_heading ) {
    wc_get_template( 'emails/email-header.php', array( 'email_heading' => $email_heading ) );
}
```

So to pass the `$email->id` we have to use a workaround, first we will make the variable global available.

---

**1)** This can be done via different hooks but the `woocommerce_email_header` hook seems to be the most suitable in this specific case:

```php
// Header - set global variable
function action_woocommerce_email_header( $email_heading, $email ) {
    $GLOBALS['email_id'] = $email->id;
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', 'action_woocommerce_email_header', 10, 2 );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

**2)** Then in the desired template file you can use:

*2.1)* put this just after `if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {..}`

```php
// Getting the email ID global variable
$ref_name_globals_var = isset( $GLOBALS ) ? $GLOBALS : '';
$email_id = isset( $ref_name_globals_var['email_id'] ) ? $ref_name_globals_var['email_id'] : '';
```

*2.2)* and at the desired location, towards the output

```php
// Targeting specific email. Multiple statuses can be added, separated by a comma
if ( in_array( $email_id, array( 'new_order', 'customer_processing_order' ) ) ) {
    // Desired output
    echo '<p style="color: red; font-size: 20px;">Your output</p>';
}
```